# Не знаючи — не поймёшь

Tags: пунктуация

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как правильнее написать выражение "не знаючи — не поймёшь". Допустимо ли без тире?

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Comment: А вот на сайте Большой вопрос сразу нельзя принимать ответ (только через несколько дней). Это делается для того, чтобы ответили все желающие, а автор мог бы выбрать наиболее понятный для него ответ.  Поэтому я не стала бы торопить автора с  "галочкой", ну хотя бы дня два-три.

Comment: @Sharon Большинство после вразумительного ответа больше не заходят. Aer тоже так делает. Да и галочку всегда можно отменить. Это не играет никакой роли. Да и через пару дней искать вопрос и оставлять комментарий — не вариант. Другое дело, что система эту информацию не предоставляет. Сам долгое время не мог понять, как здесь всё работает. Да и разбираться желания не было.

Comment: Примечание: Галочка может быть только одна.

Comment: А почему, интересно, нельзя поставить галочки обоим ответившим?

Comment: Это неправильно, я считаю.

Comment: @ВладиславВалерьевич Согласен. Но галочка — это лучший ответ, который дал более ценную информацию. Теперь, имея больше 15 баллов, можете ставить лайки ответам (любым на сайте) — нажимать на верхний серый треугольник.

Comment: На новом ресурсе сразу непросто бывает сориентироваться. Признателен вам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Не знаючи*** — разговорная деепричастная форма, нейтральный вариант — ***не зная.***

Как известно, деепричастия могут обозначать как второе действие, так и признак другого действия (в этом случае они переходят в наречие и обычно не обособляются).

Вариант ***не знаючи*** в большей степени будет проявлять **признаки наречия,** но и в качестве деепричастия он также применяется. Также важно учитывать **расстановку ударений:** *А не знАючи, лучше не совАться* (деепричастие). *Глянешь не знАючи — нет под скалой никаких ежей* (наречие).

Соответственно,  выбор знака препинания зависит **от конкретного предложения**, от расстановки логических ударений в нем, то есть для решения Вашей задачи нужен **контекст.**

**Варианты выглядят примерно так:**

*ХотЕл бы понять, да не знаючи не поймЁшь* (не паузы и нет ударения на деепричастии).

*ВЫучишь язык — будешь понимАть, а не знАючи — не поймЁшь* (тире обозначает паузу, ударение падает на деепричастие

**Грамматическая справка:**

Обычно деепричастия несовершенного вида образуются  от основы глагола настоящего времени с помощью суффикса  А/Я: дышит – дыша, говорит – говоря.

Ряд глаголов образуют деепричастия от основы настоящего времени с помощью суффиксов **УЧИ/ЮЧИ** (играючи, крадучись), а также от основы прошедшего времени  с помощью суффикса ВШИ (не знавши), но эти формы являются разговорными (кроме *будучи*).

Примеры: *Петер играючи выиграл этот спор. Будучи в Казани, Пушкин объехал все окрестности. То-то не знавши говорить не надо.*

Comment: Я где-то так и рассуждал. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

*Не знаючи* — это украинский.

*Не знавши [зная] — не поймёшь.*
Все формы деепричастий: [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/знать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

В такого рода предложениях по типу пословиц части противопоставляются, поэтому лучше через тире.

Деепричастия обособляются пунктуационо — без знака не получится.
Но можно использовать запятую. Но разные стилистические оттенки:
*Не зная, не поймёшь.* || Так понять не сможешь.
*Не зная — не поймёшь.* || Глубокое противопоставление: *если не знаешь — понять не сможешь; не будешь знать — не сможешь понять*.

Comment: Спасибо большое!